# Azure File storage - Uploading more than 4MB

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We are creating a RESTfull file service to do file operations in `Azure File storage`. We cannot upload a file more than 4MB. We tried to disable MD5Validation. But we didn't get proper documentation for that.

How can we upload more than 4MB file? How can we disable `MD5Validation` while uploading a file?

Reference:

`https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn194276.aspx`

Comment: Please share your code and also the error you're getting.

Comment: Similarly, what language are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to upload a range which is larger than 4MB? If so, please split the request into multiple requests as the [API doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn194276.aspx) mentions:

> For an update operation, the range can be up to 4 MB in size.

As for MD5 validation, if you don't specify the HTTP header Content-MD5, the server won't validate it.

> **Optional**. An MD5 hash of the content. This hash is used to verify the integrity of the data during transport. **When the Content-MD5 header is specified**, the File service compares the hash of the content that has arrived with the header value that was sent. If the two hashes do not match, the operation will fail with error code 400 (Bad Request).